# (Rancher) Longhorn too many refreshes / connections on dashboard

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, iis-6, longhorn

I am using longhorn for my k3s cluster. My cluster is in a completely different environment than my local computer. The setup for accessing the dashboard looks like this.

Local PC (env1) <-> Reverse Proxy (env1, IIS6) <-> Reverse Proxy (env2, IIS8) <-> K3s Cluster (env2 nginx ingress) <-> Longhorn dashboard (env2)

This setup works fine for most of my apps. Like Kubernetes dashboard, graylog, some self developed stuff etc.

But longhorn is reloading stuff so many times, that all ephemeral windows ports on the first Reverse Proxy are getting occupied. And then, no other connection to the server is possible anymore. Also closing all ports needs a restart of IIS. Also then, getting all connections closed needs some time. So it is creating a high pressure on the server.

My question is, is there something wrong with my IIS configuration? I am using ARR on IIS 6. It is a default configuration, nothing special. Done on the user interface with the URL Rewrite module.

Or is there a setting for longhorn, where i can disable the relaod of the page?

Here is a screenshot of my browser. As you can see, many requests are sent to the server:

[image]

Comment: The browser does indeed make multiple requests for the same file, can you see the response status code for the first request for the file, or does it keep repeating the request without a response?

Comment: When you have multiple reverse proxy servers and clusters, the best way to troubleshoot is to temporarily disable them. Directly access the origin server where the application is located to ensure that this problem does not occur and then troubleshoot the IIS or nginx cluster. This method is also recommended when troubleshooting IIS and nginx clusters. Please focus on the requests and responses from IIS8 to the nginx cluster to Longhorn, preferably to see if all requests are sent to the same server in the cluster.

Comment: Hi @BruceZhang i accessed the reverse proxy in env2 and had no such a problem. Return code for our env1 IIS6 is 101. it is also saying "switching protocols". In our env2 IIS8 i see no return code. But i can see, that this is a web socket. Maybe this is the reason why it is not working. Web Socket was introduced with iis8.